# SQL Turn Column headers into Row

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, unpivot

I'm fairly new to SQL so please forgive this.

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
| Vehicle |  Kms  |  6  | 12  | 18  |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+
|  Car    | 30000 | 53% | 50% | 47% |
|  Car    | 40000 | 50% | 47% | 44% |
|  Bus    | 50000 | 47% | 44% | 42% |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----+
```

The number in the header row are actually years, and I want to aggregate them into an 'Age' column like so.

```
+---------+-------+-----+------------+
| Vehicle |  Kms  | Age | Percentage |
------------------------+------------+
|  Car    | 30000 | 6   |   53%      |
|  Car    | 30000 | 12  |   50%      |
|  Car    | 30000 | 12  |   47%      |
|  Car    | 40000 | 6   |   50%      |
+---------+-------+-----+------------+
```

I've looked into using PIVOT but I don't want to aggregate the Kms column.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The method that I would recommend is a combination of `join` and `case` where the you join to your pivot table and then use case to select the values you want.

Different databases may have other more efficient non ANSI solutions, so if it is good to know what database you are using and whether or not you want to stick to pure ANSI for portability or tune optimally for your platform.

Two choices for the join:

1. Provide the join table inline:

   ```
   SELECT
     `Vehicle`,
     `Age`,
     CASE when `Age` = 6 then `6`
        when `Age` = 12 then `12`
        when `Age` = 18 then `18`
     END as `Percent`
   FROM 
     t1, (select 6 as `Age` union all
          select 12 as `Age` union all
          select 18 as `Age`
          ) as age_pivot;
   ```

   SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb147/4)
2. Construct the join table first and then join to it:

   ```
   SELECT
     `Vehicle`,
     `Age`,
     CASE when `Age` = 6 then `6`
          when `Age` = 12 then `12`
          when `Age` = 18 then `18`
     END as `Percent`
   FROM t1, age_pivot;
   ```

   SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d449c2/1)

The second becomes handy to keep your query reasonably consise as the size of your pivot table grows.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `union all`

```
select vehicle, kms, '6' as age, `6` as percentage from table t
union all
select vehicle, kms, '12' as age, `12` as percentage from table t
union all
select vehicle, kms, '18' as age, `18` as percentage from table t;
```

If you have large data, there are other methods that do not require three table scans, but this works for moderate amounts of data.

If you only want this for cars, then the most efficient ways is to use a `where` clause for each subquery.